# How to integrate http://j.mp into Wordpress blog?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, integration, bit.ly

In my Wordpress Blog I'm currently using an integrated http://U.nu url-shortener.

For this I've got in functions.php

```
function getunuUrl($url) {
    $unuurl = file_get_contents("http://u.nu/unu-api-simple?url=".$url);
    return $unuurl;
}
```

and in my post.php

```
<?php $uurl = getunuUrl(get_permalink($post->ID)); 
echo '<a href="'.$uurl.'">Short Url</a>' ?>
```

I can't find a way to integrate j.mp the same way. Anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like j.mp is a mirror of bit.ly
According to [bitly API](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/shorten):

```
http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version=2.0.1&longUrl=http://cnn.com&login=bitlyapidemo&apiKey=R_0da49e0a9118ff35f52f629d2d71bf07
```

I shoul change function getunuUrl (or add a new one):

```
function getunuUrl($url) {
    $unuurl = file_get_contents("http://api.bit.ly/shorten?version=2.0.1&longUrl=".$url."&login=bitlyapidemo&apiKey=R_0da49e0a9118ff35f52f629d2d71bf07");
    return $unuurl;
}
```

Don't forget to change login & apiKey to your own.

Comment: Aww, forget it then. I'm not gonna get an account when I can have one for free at U.nu. Thanks though! Appreciate it!